# Lambda capture, [ ] vs [&] and calling a member function of a class object

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I have a `class.h` file:

```
class foo {
public:
    int lengthyfunction(int& x, int y){
        int z = 0;
        for(count = 1; count <= 1000000000; count++)
            z = x + 1;
        printf("Address of x in function is %p\n", &x);
        printf("Address of y in function is %p\n", &y);
        printf("Address of count in function is %p\n", &count);
        printf("Address of object in function is %p\n", this);
        return x / y;
    }
private:
    int count;
};
```

and a `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include "class.h"

auto measure = [&](double& time, auto&& function, auto&&... parameters) -> decltype(auto){
//A lambda that accepts an arbitrary function and records its computational time
    const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point startTimePoint = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
    decltype(auto) returnValue = std::forward<decltype(function)>(function)(std::forward<decltype(parameters)>(parameters)...);
 
    const std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point stopTimePoint = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
 
    const std::chrono::duration<double> timeSpan = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(stopTimePoint - startTimePoint);
 
    std::cout << "Computation took " << timeSpan.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
    
    time = timeSpan.count();
    printf("Address of time in lambda is %p\n", &time);
 
    return returnValue;
};

int main() {
    foo f;
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto function = std::bind(&foo::lengthyfunction, f, _1, _2);
    double ftime;
    int x = 20;
    int y = 10;
    printf("Address of x in main is %p\n", &x);
    printf("Address of y in main is %p\n", &y);
    printf("Address of object in main is %p\n", &f);
    printf("Address of time in main is %p\n", &ftime);
    printf("---\n");
    decltype(auto) result = measure(ftime, function, x, y);
    getchar();
}
```

Specifically, note that `auto measure = [&](double& time, auto&& function, auto&&... parameters) -> decltype(auto)` in `main.cpp` the capture is `[&]`, by reference.

The output of this, on my Windows machine Visual Studio Release build is:

```
Address of x in main is 00000022DD8FFC44
Address of y in main is 00000022DD8FFC40
Address of object in main is 00000022DD8FFC48
Address of time in main is 00000022DD8FFC50
---
Address of x in function is 00000022DD8FFC44
Address of y in function is 00000022DD8FFC00
Address of count in function is 00000022DD8FFC64
Address of object in function is 00000022DD8FFC64
Computation took 3.01977 seconds.
Address of time in lambda is 00000022DD8FFC50
```

I can understand that since `lengthyfunction` accepts `x` by reference, the address of `x` is the same in main as well as the function. Similar reasoning for `time`. Likewise, I understand that the address of `y` is *different* between main and the function since it is not passed by reference, even though the capture is `[&]`. Fine thus far.

(Q1)What is, however, surprising is why the address of the `foo` object is different between main and the function? Isn't the function being called via the `measure` call of the same object defined in main ?

---

Removing the `&` in the capture and having that thus:

`auto measure = [](double& time, auto&& function, auto&&... parameters) -> decltype(auto)`

gave different addresses but the same underlying result (`x` and `time` addresses same in main and function, `y` and `foo` object address different.) For completion, here was the result in this case:

```
Address of x in main is 0000001892CFFDD4
Address of y in main is 0000001892CFFDD0
Address of object in main is 0000001892CFFDD8
Address of time in main is 0000001892CFFDE0
---
Address of x in function is 0000001892CFFDD4
Address of y in function is 0000001892CFFD90
Address of count in function is 0000001892CFFDF4
Address of object in function is 0000001892CFFDF4
Computation took 3.03224 seconds.
Address of time in lambda is 0000001892CFFDE0
```

(Q2)Is there any reason to prefer `[]` over `[&]` in this case ? In most cases, I would prefer to use `[&]` so as to avoid unnecessary and unintended copies of objects being made.

Comment: `std::bind` **copies its arguments**. If you need to pass by reference, pass `std::reference_wrapper`: `std::bind(&foo::lengthyfunction, std::ref(f), _1, _2);`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yes, that worked. Once that is passed by reference, is there any need to use `[&]` in the lambda capture? Also, is there any need for any other form of reference wrapping to ensure that other arguments to functions are also passed by reference? For the latter question, I suppose the answer is that there is no need since the `lengthyfunction` signature will ensure which is passed by value and which by reference. But I want to check anyway. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You misuse capture by reference (`[&]`). It is used when the lambda is defined with a scope then `[&]` capture-by-reference allows you to use all variables of within the scope. Only used variables within the lambda are meant to be captured.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I suppose my question is should `_1` be something like `std::ref(_1)` or so since the first argument, `x` is passed by reference. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref seems to give an example where there is correspondence between a passed by reference argument and a `std::ref` and between a passed by const reference and a `std::cref`.

Comment: @ALX23z If I understand correctly, since `double& time, auto&& function, auto&&... parameters` are all passed to the lambda, they are local to it and since the lambda body does not use any other variable, there is no need to use `[&]`. My confusion comes because `f` and `x` in the function need to be the ones defined in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure why use `std::bind` at all. A lambda does the same thing 99% of the time. No, you should not do `std::ref(_1)`, this makes no sense. `std::bind` copies *bound* arguments. `_1` is not a bound argument, it is a placeholder.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Could you please indicate how to not use std::bind in this case ? I got this code from **incidentally** from one of your answers from years ago! https://ideone.com/z2nsc3. I essentially liked your solution there in that it does not require me to individually query the time before a function, call the function, then poll the time again afterwards. I thought the approach you had there was much more intuitive and readable. Some of my functions within the class take other big class objects by reference and hence I am paranoid about inadvertently passing by value these.